# JavaMail subject encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, jakarta-mail

In my project I have downloaded one of my personal email from Thunderbird. I opened it with my text editor and the email Subject looks like this:

> =?utf-8?B?some_chars_here_1==?==?utf-8?B?some_chars_here_2?=

where I've hidden the actual characters with the strings some_chars_here_1 and some_chars_here_2.
I read the message in this way:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, inputStream);
```

When I tried to get the email subject via

```
message.getSubject()
```

I get something like:

> first_part_well_encoded=?utf-8?B?some_chars_here_2?=

So I did it in this way:

```
public String getSubject(MimeMessage message) {
    String subject = message.getHeader("Subject", null);
    String parts[] = subject.split("\\=\\?u");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : parts) {
        if (string.length() > 3) {
            string = "=?u" + string;
            stringBuilder.append(
                     MimeUtility.decodeText(MimeUtility.unfold(string)));
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And now the Subject is correct. I am wondering: is this the best way to do this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailer that created that message is broken.  There should be a space between the two encoded words.  Please report this bug to the owner of the mailer.

To work around this problem, try setting the System property `mail.mime.decodetext.strict` to `false`.

Comment: Did you report the bug to the owner of the mailer?

Comment: Yes, I sent an email to them about the issue